# Regex to match 2 identical character classes in different places

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to work out if I can condense a number of regex's into a single one, but can't quite get there.

I'm trying to look for a matched pair of characters, which could be one from a range.

eg

```
1 text 1     <--- This is a match
1 text 2     <--- This is not a match
2 text 1     <--- This is a match
```

The list of options is finite, so I know I could just test each case separately, eg:

```
1(.+?)1
2(.+?)2
```

However, I was trying to use grouping to do this in one query. Something along the lines of:

```
[1-8](.+?)[1-8]
```

But this (incorrectly) matches:

```
1 text 2     <--- This is not a match
```

Is there a way I can ensure that the second bracketed list match is the same as the match in the first bracket? ie If the first matches the 1 then the second must also be 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use groups and then refer to that group

```
([1-8])(?:.+?)\1
```

`\1` refers to the `first` captured group i.e `([1-8])`

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [back reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

```
([1-8])(.+?)\1
```

That way the front and back characters would have to match for the whole thing to be considered a match.